# Display settings window only once

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I would like to open a settings window only once, first time i open my app.
After that, this settings window will doesn't display anymore and it will display the main view of the app.

I don't know how can i solve this problem, because the Storyboard only has one initial ViewController, and i would need two (a ViewController with settings, and other ViewController with my main view).

How can i choose between my both ViewController?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to use user defaults -- register a default, say something like setBool:TRUE forKey:@"NeverOpened", and then check that value. If it is true, have your main view controller modally present the settings controller, and then when that is dismissed, set the value of the "NeverOpened" key to false. Next time the app is opened, NeverOpened will be false, and the settings controller won't be presented.

Answer (score 0):

In you main view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method check for first-app-start and if so, push the settings controller without an animation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be broken down into two parts. First, to determine if a user has run the application before, you need to query something that is persistent across all the times the user runs the application. For small bits of data, you can use NSUserDefaults, which is basically a dictionary. When you query NSUserDefaults, if there is no object for a corresponding key, NSUserDefaults returns nil. Taking advantage of this, we can query for a key like "hasRunKey". If it returns nil, the user hasn't run the app before and we should set the object for hasRunKey so we don't get nil in the future.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"hasRunKey"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"hasRunKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    // Present the settings view controller -- see explanation below. 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"My Identifier" sender:self];
} else {
    // Do what you normally do. 
}
```

For the second problem, displaying the settings view controller, you should add a new file and subclass UIViewController with some sort of MySettingsViewController class. Then, in your storyboard, drag out a UIViewController object from the side panel. In that view controller's identity inspector, set the class to the MySettingsViewController you just created. (See this image for the relevant places: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s230/sh/ac134774-530f-4649-b3a2-e46b8d712c78/0352134cc8fab7241d97292f4d6ff464 ).

Select your first view controller and Ctrl+drag to the MySettingsViewController to create a segue between the two. Click on the segue you created in the storyboard and give it an identifier, using the attributes inspector window. You can also choose how you'd like to present the view controller at this point; I recommend modal for your purposes.

As Nikolai recommended, the viewDidLoad method of your first view controller is a good place for this code.

I strongly recommend watching e.g. Paul Hegerty's iTunes U lectures on iOS development--it covers these fundamentals like using storyboards and segueing between them.